# Looping code causes stack overflow

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, stack-overflow

I have this code:

```
 public static void Detect (String[] args) throws Exception {

        PointerInfo pointer; /* needed for getting cursor location */
        pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point coord = pointer.getLocation();

        Robot cursor = new Robot(); /*Creates a new robot */
        cursor.delay(500); /* robot delay */

        /**
         * detection method
         * Works by looking at pixel color underneath mouse.
         * If RED is over > a value and GREEN is under < a value then loop
         * If criteria is not matched go to Something
         */
        while(true) {
            coord = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();       
            Color color = cursor.getPixelColor((int)coord.getX(), (int)coord.getY());
            if(color.getRed() >= 75 && color.getGreen() < 100 ){
                Detect(args);

            }
            else{        
                System.out.println(color);
                Something(args);


            }
            cursor.delay(1000);

        }
   }
```

And I know this is probably the worst implementation possible. Calling a void to create a loop causes stack overflow. Could someone please explain how I can make this whole code segment do the same thing but loop using "while"?

Here is the stacktrace btw:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.MouseInfo.areScreenDevicesIndependent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.MouseInfo.getPointerInfo(Unknown Source)
at com.meganukebmp.Main.Detect(Main.java:29)
at com.meganukebmp.Main.Detect(Main.java:45)
at com.meganukebmp.Main.Detect(Main.java:45)
at com.meganukebmp.Main.Detect(Main.java:45)
at com.meganukebmp.Main.Detect(Main.java:45)
at com.meganukebmp.Main.Detect(Main.java:45)
at com.meganukebmp.Main.Detect(Main.java:45)
at com.meganukebmp.Main.Detect(Main.java:45)
at com.meganukebmp.Main.Detect(Main.java:45)
at com.meganukebmp.Main.Detect(Main.java:45)
at com.meganukebmp.Main.Detect(Main.java:45)
```

Comment: Show us stacktrace please!

Comment: you call `Detect(args)` with the same arguments that you received. obviously this will create an endless loop. you have to call it with different args (i.e. create a copy of the args, and then modify/reduce that copy).

Answer (score 1):

If

```
if(color.getRed() >= 75 && color.getGreen() < 100 )
```

is fullfilled, you are infinitely calling the `Detect` method.

I suggest you check your `RGB` values and correct the test if it always returns `true`.

Source : [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

> The job of the recursive cases can be seen as breaking down complex
>   inputs into simpler ones. In a properly designed recursive function,
>   with each recursive call, the input problem must be simplified in such
>   a way that eventually the base case must be reached. (Functions that
>   are not intended to terminate under normal circumstances—for example,
>   some system and server processes—are an exception to this.) Neglecting
>   to write a base case, or testing for it incorrectly, can cause an
>   infinite loop.

Comment: I know that this is causing it. I'm asking for a way to fix it. Either by changing the way I loop. Or something else.

Comment: @meganukebmp I thought it was clear. Your test must be false. You know which color you're getting so look at their RGB values and check if your test is plausible.

Comment: I'm very sorry but I don't seem to understand. I'm pretty new at the language. I must return true If I want to repeat the while loop and return false when I want to exit it. Is that right? @YassinHajaj

Comment: Yes my test is plausible, If I get a color withing the values I set up it calls the other Something void. The problem is that after the Something void is done with its job it calls the Detect void again and thus loops it. Please tell me if you want to see the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Just removed the Detect(args);
While loop will allways return true so no need to loop the entire void.